# ANOVA significance visualisation of replicate experiment data (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, anova

I am struggling to get significance values of my experiment replicate data. Experiment done in duplicate for each species and i want to compare how significant the values are for each time point between each species. I am trying to do two-way ANOVA...

[image: this is what i get now as my result- but i cannot see the significance at each time point as a different value..]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)
abs2.melt<-melt(abs2,
                id.vars='Time',
                measure.vars=c('WT','WT.1','DsigB','DsigB.1','DrsbR','DrsbR.1'))
print(abs2.melt)
abs2.melt.mod<-abs2.melt %>%
  separate(col=variable,into=c('Species'),sep='\\.')
print(abs2.melt.mod)
ggplot(abs2.melt.mod,aes(x=Time,y=value,group=Species))+
  stat_summary(
    fun =mean,
    geom="line",
    aes(color=Species))+
  stat_summary(
    fun=mean,
    geom="point")+
  stat_summary(
    fun.data=mean_cl_boot,
    geom='errorbar',
    width=2)+
  theme_bw()+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("OD600")+
  labs(title="Growth Curve of Mutant Strains")
summary(abs2.melt.mod)
print(abs2.melt.mod)
###SD and mean values
as.data.frame<-abs2.melt.mod %>% group_by(Species,Time) %>% 
  summarize(mean.val=mean(value), sd.val=sd(value))
anova1<-aov(value~Species,data=abs2.melt.mod)
##statistical significance?
print(as.data.frame)
anova1<-aov(Time~Species+value,data=abs2.melt.mod)
summary(anova1)
```

[image: My data that was melted consisting of 2 replicate samples taken at each time point (30min,60min...)]

Comment: Hi @DianaGudynalte, something is weird...you need to put aov(value ~ Time + Species.. )because value is your response variable

Comment: your plot is ok. I guess your question is more about the anova?

Comment: THanks for reply but that still would make my significance value correct (i need it for each time point for each strain)

Comment: yes, you need to fit a interaction model, aov(value ~ Time * Species,..), this might be a bit hard to interpret. Let me see if there is a easier way to calculate the marginals. And you need to make Time a factor, i.e abs2.melt.mod$Time=factor(abs2.melt.mod$Time)

Comment: ok you can use emmeans, install the package, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html, make Time a factor, then emmeans(lm(value ~ Species*Time,data=df),pairwise ~Species | Time)

Comment: it worked- the comparison between each Species in their values seperated at each time interval. This will be very helpful in the future analysis. However i was looking for a simpler way just to display the significance of my mean values according to each time point of experiment..

Comment: Ok i write something to plot below, you can see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Simulate something that looks like your data

```
set.seed(111)
df = expand.grid(rep=1:3,Time=1:5,Species=letters[1:3])
df$value = 0.5*df$Time + rnorm(nrow(df))
df$Time = factor(df$Time)
```

Then we plot, allowing comparison for each time point:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=Time,y=value,col=Species)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl",position=position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

[image]

Or error bar which i think looks bad:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Time,y=value,col=Species))+
stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl",position=position_dodge(width=0.5),
geom="errorbar",width=0.4)
```

[image]
Since you have a few data points, no point doing a boxplot, so you can try something like the above